# Injecting data to database using php and sql

Tags: php, sql

I'm learning PHP and I'm having some problems with selecting and inserting data into the database. i wrote the code below to select the first part of a string select id from a whose name matches the exploded string then insert to database. when I run the cod the nothing is injected into the table . could you please help me?

```
$mine1 =; $mine ="Baringo, City";
$array = explode(',', $mine1);
$first = $array [0];

 $plancity = ORM::for_table($config['db']['pre'] . 'citie')
                    ->select('id')
                    ->where('name', $first)
                    ->find_one();
$cityr = $plancity['id'];

$item_insrt = ORM::for_table($config['db']['pre'].'Map')->create();
$item_insrt->city = $cityr;$mine1 =; $mine ="Baringo, City";
$array = explode(',', $mine1);
$first = $array [0];

 $plancity = ORM::for_table($config['db']['pre'] . 'citie')
                    ->select('id')
                    ->where('name', $first)
                    ->find_one();
$cityr = $plancity['id'];

$item_insrt = ORM::for_table($config['db']['pre'].'Map')->create();
$item_insrt->city = $cityr;
```

Comment: What are you using for the database class (`ORM`)?

Comment: Which ORM are you using? Is it a well-known one, or something you wrote yourself? That's some basic info we're going to need. Also are you seeing any errors (and do you have error reporting enabled so that you could ensure they are displayed?)